# Which one is efficient to initialize variables ie) constructor or activate method?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I want to initialize some variables in super class.

> In **OSGI** there is an method `activate()` which is called once the service/component starts. But constructor is called before the `activate` method.

Which one(`activate()` method or *constructor* ) is efficient to initialize variables in **OSGI**.

Answer (score 7):

The order in Declarative Services is:

- Constructor
- Injections of services
- Activate

It is generally best to initialize *as much as possible* in the constructor because it allows you to use `final` fields though you have of course to be aware of some of the issues around construction. Since the injections have not yet taken place you usually defer some of the initialization to the activate method. There is absolutely no difference in efficiency.

We are currently considering adding constructor injection to the OSGi R7 specification which would allow you to to bypass the injection sites and activate methods.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor and activate() have different purposes.

You use the Constructor if the initializations you want to do have to be done before anything else.

You use activate() if you need access to injected services or if you want to use config admin configuration data. So activate() is a bit like [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) in JavaEE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know OSGI but I doubt there's much of a difference in terms of efficiency. It's probably just a matter of when the initialization is done - at load time (when the instance is created) or upon first access to the component.

There's another difference though that isn't related to efficiency:

Constructors are called top-down, i.e. the super constructors are called before the sub constructors. If any of those would do some initialization work that might be overridden by a subclass, e.g. using some internal init method, the subclass' initialization code might get called before the subclass' constructor and thus you run into not yet initialized fields etc.

On the other hand using an initialization method like `activate()` would ensure that all constructors have run first (if the framework calls it after creating the instance that is).

Besides that you probably could call `activate()` multiple times without having to recreate the instance (assuming you also can deactivate a component).

That's just my 2 cents and I might be wrong (I repeat my disclaimer: I don't really know much of OSGI), but it might help you decide where to put your code.

Comment: @Thanks Thomas. Here activate() is a lifecycle method of Component. so calling multiple times activate() wouldn't appear. As you said about construtor is valid.